# Can't display special character ü (German u with 2 dots over it)

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-word, vba

I have an ActiveX combo box which is loaded from a list of names in another sheet. The name Müller displays correctly in the dropdown and in the combo box when selected, but when the worksheet selection is changed the presentation of ü in the combo box changes and all characters following the ü are displayed in another font with faulty character spacing (perhaps an Asian font). The display changes back to normal when I click the combo box again.

The font I use both in the combo box, in the original list and the rest of the sheet on which the combo box is located is Verdana. When I change the combo box's font to Arial the error disappears

The workbook has a history in that it was first created in Excel 2003. I have been editing it in Excel 2010 in compatibility mode hoping to give it back to the 2003 environment eventually. Perhaps my choice of Verdana wasn't the best, considering that Office 2003 doesn't have Verdana (I think). I was hoping to cross that bridge when I come to it but didn't expect to be confronted with it at this point or in this way.

Any suggestions what I might do?

Comment: @Gustav It seems that I rolled back your edit. That wasn't my intention. I just wanted to see what you edited and presume that you improved the post. I still don't know. Thanks anyway, though I would have preferred a suggestion. I since tried to enter the ü character using Alt+252 instead of Alt+0252 which I use since Office 2007 but I'm not sure that it was 252 in Office 2003. I just remember that it was 3-digit. Anyway, it didn't help.

Comment: It was the tags only. I removed the Word and Access tags as you mention Excel only. However, I have no idea what could cause your issue.

Comment: Thank you. Ultimately it must be the character set associated with Verdana. Hence it isn't an Excel problem and might be solved by someone who knows about fonts. Conceivably, when I write Alt(0252) in Excel 14 I get the correct character, but when Excel 12 reads the combo box it applies another character set, creating some kind of error. An Excel specialist might know why the Cbx is read at all on Selection_Change (and not on Cbx_Change, for example). I have no Selection_Change event code in this project.